# PowerPoint VBA Cell Shading

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am looking to programme a VBA code for PowerPoint that changes the colours of cells within a table depending on their values.

For example, "-2" to be Red, "0" to be Yellow and "+1" to be Green. And if these conditions are not satisfied, do not alter any colours.

Thank you!

Comment: what have you trued so far ? please share your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, not the entire code you need, but this should help you:

```
With With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(3).Table
    If .Cell(y, x).Shape.Fill.BackColor.RGB <> -2 And .Cell(y, x).Shape.Fill.BackColor.RGB <> 0 _
    And .Cell(y, x).Shape.Fill.BackColor.RGB <> 1 Then      'You might have to check an other BackGround property
        .Cell(y, x).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = 'something
    End If
End With
```

Just loop through all of our cells (increase y and x to the max. value of coloumns and rows)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Sub Test()
' Here's how you'd call RecolorTable
' Add code to set a reference to the table as required
    Dim oTbl As Table
    Set oTbl = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Table
    
    Call RecolorTable(oTbl)
    
End Sub

Sub RecolorTable(oTbl As Table)
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    With oTbl
        For lCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
            For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                With .Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape
                    Select Case .TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                        Case Is = "-2"
                            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                        Case Is = "0"
                            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                        Case Is = "+1"
                            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                        Case Else
                            ' do nothing
                    End Select
                End With
            Next
        Next
    End With
    
End Sub
```